# Array length accourding to imgs inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a slider, and create a way to count the number of img inside the div .sliderWrapper. The number of imgs will be stored in an array as it`s length, so the slider will play accourding it.

Is that possible?

```
<div class="sliderWrapper">
       <img class="image" src="img1.jpg">
       <img class="image" src="img2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.sliderWrapper .image').length`

Comment: `$('.image').length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `length` property of the object you can count the elements.

```js
 alert($('.sliderWrapper img').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderWrapper">
  <img class="image" src="img1.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="img2.jpg">
</div>
```